# Need clarity on Camel Timer component timely processing

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

In Apache Camel, I have configured the timer component to fire the job for every 15 mins. Suppose if any job which is taken more than 15 mins due to data load to complete it task, will it be affected by the next job since we have configured to run job for every 15 mins.

Comment: What is "Spring Camel"? Is your job a Spring Batch job? Are you scheduling your job with [Camel's scheduler](http://camel.apache.org/scheduler.html)? Please provide more details about your config to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, I have updated the question. This is not related to Spring batch or Camel's scheduler. This is about Apache Camel's timer component.

Comment: "This is not related to Spring batch": in that case, you can remove the spring-batch tag.

Comment: sure. I did. Thanks!

Comment: There is an option on the timer component to control that, I think its the fixedRate, its from the JDK Timer so you can also find out more about how that works but reading about the JDK Timer - https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-timer/src/main/docs/timer-component.adoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Claus already commented, the option `fixedRate` of the [Camel Timer component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-timer/src/main/docs/timer-component.adoc) controls this. The term `fixedRate` refers to the same term of [Javas `ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

The default is `fixedRate=false`. That means the Timer uses **`fixed-delay execution`** of the ExecutorService. For example

```
delay=30000&period=60000&fixedRate=false
```

means that the task runs for the first time 30s after starting. After that **a new task starts 60s after the previous task has finished**. The task can never overlap.

In contrast, `fixedRate=true` switches to **`fixed-rate execution`** of the ExecutorService. For example

```
delay=30000&period=60000&fixedRate=true
```

means that the task runs for the first time 30s after starting. After that **every 60s a new task is started, no matter how long the tasks are running**. So in this setup the tasks can overlap.

Comment: Thanks @burki. So, i hope fixedRate=false is a feasible solution. Since it's won't overlap (or) interfere the execution of the job. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes that should work without overlaps